# When writing formulae, how does one represent different "variables" of the same "type"?

Tags: conventions, notation

To explain further this question, suppose I have a formula with several references to times in it.

For example, with a computer magnetic disk, there could be the time it takes for the head move from when end to the other; then there could be the time it takes the hard disk to make one revolution; the time it takes for i/o queuing and so on.

Personally, I just use subscripts, like *t<sub>s</sub>, t<sub>d</sub>, t<sub>dr</sub>* and so on, and this works fine for me but when it comes to sharing information with others, I'd like to use the correct conventions. Is my approach acceptable?

Comment: Yes it is acceptable, and there is no unique convention.

Comment: Why the downvote? My first question and I'm penalised for asking it? Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics.

Comment: Hi Jason. I think the downvoter must be feeling grumpy today :-) Arguably this isn't an ideal question for this site but the downvote seems harsh and you have (at the time of writing) two good answers.

Comment: Amplifying the comment by @valerio92:   use subscripts that make some sense, and be sure to tell the reader what they represent.  Sounds simple, but it's sometimes overlooked.  I've read published papers containing undefined symbols leaving the meaning of the expression, and sometimes the point of the paper, obscure.  I wonder how that gets by the referees, but it does now and then.

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry too much about the first few downvotes, I don't believe they are representative of Physics SE as a whole nor necessarily reflective of your question quality. I would say only worry when a problem is *actually* brought up about your question/answer. As for why, if I had to guess, the answer to your question is fairly well-known and not really a specific, conceptual one. Although, I find it hard to phrase this question to Google and I can see how the issue is not immediately obvious to people new to Physics. I also think this question patently *is* about Physics.

Comment: @HsMjstyMstdn it's about notation when writing formulae. Not strictly physics, since formulae appear in all sciences. In any event, not every physics question possible is considered on topic, so just because it might be 'about physics' didn't mean we could it should answer it.

Comment: @KyleKanos I would say this is about a specific problem in notation that shows up a lot of the time in physics i.e., how to deal with labelling multiple instances of the same variable but I see your point. It might not be specifically about physics but I still think it *is* about physics. I also think such a question might be useful to future visitors of the site.  That being said, it seems like my view is in the minority here.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinite versions of time to define. What about the time for half a revolution? Or a third? Or a tenth? We could go on.

It is impossible to have unique conventions for each possible scenario. Instead we just use some often-used symbols for the "main" or "general" version and add subscripts like you showed. Or you can invent a completely new symbol for a specific case, if you prefer.

Note that many variables do not have symbols according to any convention. Something as fundamental as a general **length** is given various symbols - often $l$ or $L$, sometimes $d$ for distance, in specific cases $r$ or $R$ for radius, $h$ and $w$ for height and width, maybe even a language-specific $s$ (short for "sted", meaning "place" in Danish) etc. Contexts, wording and even language will influence the choice. Of this reason you can never expect people to know what you mean purely from the symbol of a variable (except for in certain applied cases, such as labeled $\cos(\varphi)$ on generators e.g.), so you must always fully define a variable the first time it is used in an article, paper, or so.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you define them fully the first time you use them, that should be fine e.g. "The time for one revolution ($t_r$) and the time for i/o queuing ($t_q$) are..."